# How can I position my html elements in the layout I created with photoshop?

Tags: html, layout

I created some graphic layouts by photoshop and made it the background for my website.
But I am clueless as to how I can put html elements in the right place. The problem is, the positions of html elements change by the size of the browser. How can I solve this problem? Any clues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to learn CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/20_websites_learn_master_css/).

- Be patient.
- Be persistent.
- Learn what IE versions baulk at what.

Comment: Can you let me know what kinda properties in CSS I have to use in order to achive what I want?

Comment: Or can you recommend me relavant website to learn it, if any?

Comment: @SEA There is a link in my answer to 20 different sites. As for properties you want, I have no idea without seeing your design, but it sounds like you want `position: absolute`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will start from them.

Answer (score 1):

You must know how to use CSS specially the html elements positioning.

- [Positioning HTML Elements with Cascading Style Sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-970131)
- [Positioning schemes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme)

Also be careful with different browser because the display result may differ for every browser.

Answer (score 1):

start here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwQMnpUsj8I

Once you understand the basics, check out grid systems like this:  http://960.gs/